# How to display digit in android?

Tags: android

I'd like to write a game. Here is my question:
How do I display digits in android like temple run and other android games do to display the score in corner?
I don't want to use the plain text view, which is lame and does not suit the whole UI.

Comment: How do you display the rest of the UI?

Comment: Whatever library you are using will have an XYZ.writeText or something equivalent. You could use a text view with a transparent background.

Comment: @Hyperboreus The ui is in relative-layout. I'd like to know to diplay the fancy digit, should I use imageview or should I use a fancy font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is find a fancy typeface and apply that to the textview

Something like this

```
    Typeface customtypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
        "helvetica-neue-ultra-light.otf");
textview.setTypeface(customtypeface);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but where should I put the font file?

Comment: It seems that using the font cause the text to be only black. Is there any way to make the txt colorful?

Comment: The file should be in your assets and you can change the textcolor the same way by doing textview.setcolor